# Libraries disappeared from Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, libraries

On my Windows 7 installation, the Library view disappeared from my navigation pane in Windows Explorer. They can be accessed via Desktop still, but is there a way to get the library back as a separate item in the Navigation Pane?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure this will work in your case but I think its better to try something than nothing. After I disabled it purposely this procedure is what I followed to enable Libraries again.

**1)** WinKey+R

**2)** Type regedit and Click OK

**3)**  Navigate to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{031E4825-7B94-4dc3-B131-E946B44C8DD5}\ShellFolder

**4)** Select the Shell Folder Folder then Go to Edit Menu  >>  Select Permissions. Permissions Widow will pop -up , Under security Tab  >> Select Administrator >> Tick Full Control >> click Apply and  OK.

**5)** When you select the Shell Folder, in the right pane you will find Attributes  >> Select The Attribute  >> go to Edit Menu >> Click on Modify >> Input this value  b080010d

**6)** Make sure the Base is opted for Hexadecimal

**7)** Click OK

**8)** Restart

Answer (score 0):

If the navigation pane only shows the Desktop, and the Libraries as child item, this is easy to fix:

[image]

Just right-click on the free area below the icons in the navigation pane and de-select the option "Show all folders".

Then, the Libraries are again shown as a separate item in the navigation pane:

[image]